# Duplicate Data in Chunks ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to use an ASP.NET 5 Controller to load data into the DataTables plugin. However I'm getting duplicate rows. I examined the response in Fiddler and I am receiving duplicated data in the separate chunks that are returned.

How do I stop this?

My function is pretty simple:

```
public IActionResult GetData()
{
    TableData tableData = new TableData();
    tableData.data = _db.DatatbaseObject.ToList();
    return Ok(tableData);
}
```

Please can you help me sort this out... I would post the result but it has some sensitive data in but looks something like this:

```
2000
{"data":[{dataObj1},{dataObj2}].....
2000
{"data":[{dataObj3},{dataObj1}].....
```

Comment: I'm using rc1-update-1 and DNX x64 CoreCLR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears that the chunking isn't responsible for the duplicate data.

However, to prevent the chunking I found the following solution:

```
string JsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tableData);
var headers = Response.GetTypedHeaders();
headers.ContentLength = JsonString.Length;
headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue { NoCache = true, Public = true };
```

Hope this helps someone.